# Is there anyway I can manage all the email operations of the cPanel by PHP?

Tags: php, cpanel

I want to manage all the Email operations that are listed in the image below (image is in the link) by using PHP code. For example, I want to create a mailbox with a PHP code from my website. Is that possible or is there any way I can do that?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WIyXUyAAktZC8fNfmWlg-eAyZzISAfDc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can write another email control panel in PHP (similar to ISPConfig) which interacts with your email server.  But I think it takes a few months for an average programmer to complete this project.